# cli-plugin-ionic1: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, ionic-cli

I ran `ionic serve` in the Ionic v1 template.(https://github.com/jdnichollsc/Ionic-ElastiChat-with-Images.git)
It asked me to install the Gulp plugin and `cli-plugin-ionic1` and I installed them.
But it crashes with the following logs:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
 ...node_modules/@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic1/dist/serve/live-reload.js:19:29)
    at ReadFileContext.fs.readFile [as callback] (.../node_modules/@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic1/dist/serve/http-server.js:59:39)
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:365:13)

I am using the latest version of Ionic CLI.
How can I make it running?

Comment: Did you solve it? I'm facing the exact same error

Comment: Never, I am waiting for a good solution yet.

Comment: My resolution for this was to run the serve as a privileged user. My permissions were all wonky.